# Why an aggregation function doesn't work as expected in an apply block

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH
    a (v)
    AS
        (    SELECT LEVEL
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5),
    b (v)
    AS
        (    SELECT LEVEL
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5)
SELECT a.v
  FROM a
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN (b.v)
                      FROM b
                     WHERE a.v = b.v) bb
```

result 1,2,3,4
but expected result would be 1,1,1,1.

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1540d1694341ed0b89d953398eda99b2)

Comment: Why do you expect it to be `1,1,1,1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1,2,3,4` is the correct output.

In the outer query you `SELECT a.v` which will select the `v` value from table `a` `CROSS JOIN` with the single row aggregation generated by the `CROSS APPLY`.

For your code, it doesn't really matter what the output is from the `bb` sub-query in the `CROSS APPLY` as you are not outputting the value from `bb` and the aggregation forces the output to be a single row.

---

If you want to get the value from the `bb` sub-query then use:

```sql
WITH a (v) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
),
b (v) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
)
SELECT a.v, bb.min_v
  FROM a
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT MIN (b.v) As min_v
         FROM   b
         WHERE  a.v = b.v
       ) bb
```

Then the output is:

> | V | MIN_V |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 |
> | 3 | 3 |
> | 4 | 4 |

If you want all `1`s then `SELECT` the value from `bb` and use `b.v <= a.v` as the filter:

```sql
WITH a (v) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
),
b (v) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
)
SELECT a.v, bb.min_v
  FROM a
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT MIN (b.v) As min_v
         FROM   b
         WHERE  b.v <= a.v
       ) bb
```

which outputs:

> | V | MIN_V |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 1 |
> | 3 | 1 |
> | 4 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6310093b9db94261a14b1e9f02411b24)*

Answer (score 1):

I guess, everything works as expected. Your cross-apply is evaluated per-row.
So when you push there a.v=1 the query to be evaluated is

SELECT MIN (b.v)
FROM b WHERE 1= b.v

Then you provide a.v=2 and the query to be evaluated is

SELECT MIN (b.v)
FROM b WHERE 2= b.v